Update new GUID based on non-unique column in same table
I have a requirement in SQL server query on updating new Guid for null records based on another non-unique column.  Tried out update statement with group by and that gives error. Also, tried joining same table using distinct join. That updates unique records for each row. So, can someone tell me is there a way to write a SQL query to get below expected result output? If I need to iterate each row in loop and check the id value appears to me a costly move. Looking forward smart query to update with out looping.
For example, consider sample dbo.Products Table and it contains Product_Ref_Id and Product_Name.



Product_Ref_Id
Product_Name




NULL
Product1


NULL
Product1


NULL
Product1


NULL
Product2


NULL
Product2


NULL
Product2



In the above table, the Product_Ref_Id is to be updated with same GUID for Product1 and another GUID applies to Product2 rows. So, the query should give below output



Product_Ref_Id
Product_Name




28079cfa-2384-48c6-bf5b-488a31d33bdb
Product1


28079cfa-2384-48c6-bf5b-488a31d33bdb
Product1


28079cfa-2384-48c6-bf5b-488a31d33bdb
Product1


f40b7c2d-873e-48b6-b2c4-d01d2d7258bf
Product2


f40b7c2d-873e-48b6-b2c4-d01d2d7258bf
Product2


f40b7c2d-873e-48b6-b2c4-d01d2d7258bf
Product2



Appreciate your great help on this. Thanks.

So what is your question here?

SQL Query to get the desired output. I asked in the beginning, right? Is it not clear?

That isn't a questionn. "I need" tells us what you want, but not what you are asking. What is the difficulty you are having solving the problem? What have you tried? Why didn't it work? What about the resources online didn't you understand?

ok. let me update the question with difficulties I faced.

Does this answer your question? Generate and repeat NEWID() values in a single query

@Viswa are all the values of Product_Ref_Id null ? Not related to the question but why using GUID over intigers ?

That is the requirement. @Ergest.

@ThomA, I am facing two challenges on your suggestion. one is Invalid Object name GENERATE_SERIES and the other cannot update GUID using cross apply example.

You should have a table with one row per product, eg
create table Product
(
  Product_Ref_Id uniqueidentifier primary key default newid(), 
  Product_Name varchar(200)
)

Then load that table with the new Product_Names.  Then the other table you no longer need the Product_Name.
This is basic normalization for both OLTP and Dimensional modeling.

HI David, Thanks for the suggestion. I know this type of table creation. In my project, the real table has 20 columns and that is mapped with other tables. I cannot introduce new table for this scenario, rather I can try looping each record and compare and update.

If I understood your requirements correctly maybe the following might help.
The CTE will generate a unique GUID for each distinct Product_Name.
WITH productGUID AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Product_Name,
                    NEWID() AS guid
    FROM Products
)
UPDATE p
SET Product_Ref_Id = pg.guid
FROM Products p
INNER JOIN productGUID pg ON p.Product_Name = pg.Product_Name;

See example
Further reading SQL Server : does NEWID() always gives a unique ID?

CTE should be select Product_Name, max(Product_Ref_id) guid from Products GROUP BY Product_Name).  Otherwise that could mess up existing data.

@DavidBrowne-Microsoft Why ? . What is the point of max(Product_Ref_id) ?  DISTINCT Product_Name,NEWID() AS guid is the same as SELECT Product_Name,NEWID() AS guid FROM t GROUP BY Product_Name,guid , please correct me if I am wrong. In the fiddle it gives what OP is asking

What if some Product_Name's have an existing Product_Ref_Id?  What if only some rows for a Product_Name have an existing Product_Ref_id?

@DavidBrowne-Microsoft I did ask that on the comment section, no answer from the OP on that matter. So I will let the answer be as it is at the moment

Let's say you have a table with following data:
select CAST(product_ref_id AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) AS product_ref_id
,   Product_Name
into #data
from (
    VALUES  (NULL, N'Product1')
    ,   (NULL, N'Product1')
    ,   (NULL, N'Product1')
    ,   (NULL, N'Product2')
    ,   (NULL, N'Product2')
    ,   (NULL, N'Product2')
) t (Product_Ref_Id,Product_Name)

You can set the id by doing a partitioned MAX NEWID call:
update t
set Product_Ref_Id = t.newID
from    ( 
    select  MAX(NEWID()) OVER(PARTITION BY Product_name) as newID
    ,   Product_Ref_Id
    FROM    #data
    ) t

This selects Maximum NEWID based on product_name and updates the table in one pass with the new value.
